# Is the language comment supported?

Tags: support, formatting

Does tor.SE support the `language` comment for specifying the language of formatted code?

In my answer https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/667/66 I use

```
<!-- language: lang-sh -->
```

in front of a block of shell code. This has no visible effect.

Is the `language` comment supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't currently have that feature enabled, however we can get Stack Exchange to enable it!

To do this we need to clearly show why our community needs it enabled.

I've made this answer a community wiki, so that our case can be collected in one simple place.

I suggest we start by collecting questions (and answers) which contain code that would benefit from having syntax highlighting.

**Questions and Answers that will benefit**

- [Script to verify checksums of Tor Browser Bundle Downloads](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/648/how-to-verify-tor-browser-bundle-tbb-3-x/667#667)
- [Script to calculate the number of possible distinct Tor circuits](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/690/66)

Comment: A service has features, but one can not use these features until it is proven that it is required? Is this only for beta? Let's consider auto-translation (featured pulled from my ass) after beta, could it be enabled/disabled by a Tor moderators or does it require SE to be involved?

Comment: You could probably make the argument that, since this is a technical site, and some Tor configuration may involve some shell scripting, that having syntax highlighting would be helpful. I would just... ask...

Comment: @bastik This feature has to be enabled by SE.  And yes, we have to show that we have need of it. I believe this is a general requirement, not limited to the Beta period.

Comment: @jmort253 If you know of any additional questions that have shell scripting, please add them to the list. I already have asked, and making a strong case, formed by the community, is how they decide whether to enable it.

Comment: If your volume of code / programming questions continues to rise, please feel free to ping me and I can see about getting this enabled.